# Does HP DeskJet Ink Advantage 3635 WiFi (F5S44C) work with Ubuntu 16.04LTS?

Tags: networking, drivers, printing, hp

I'm thinking to buy a wifi hp color printer, I like the HP DeskJet Ink Advantage 3635 with Wi-Fi (F5S44C) + USB cable model.
Does it work fine with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS ?
Does WiFi work fine?
Does scan and copy work fine too?
Is it easy to install?
Are drivers available and easy to install?
I'm an Ubuntu newbie so if it requires hard knowledge to install it please advise me.
I want to buy a cheap wifi multifunction color printer for home use, if you have good experiences with other models please write it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The best place to answer such questions regarding hp printers is:

http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/deskjet_aio/deskjet_3630_series.html

```
Distro  Version Installer   GUI14   Scan3   Fax5    Status  Photo Card4 USB Parallel    Network
Ubuntu  16.04       Yes     Yes (Qt4)Yes     No     Yes      No        Yes     No         Yes
```

In short, the printer should work fine without a proprietary driver plug in.

Comment: As you are a reputation 1 user. If this answered your question, please accept it by clicking on the tick mark on the left of the question.